# Pointfree Composition with Multiple Variables

Tags: haskell, function-composition, pointfree

I've started to wrap my head around it, and rather like using it for simple situations in which I can essentially pipe the values from one output to one input. A simple example of a pointfree composition I'm comfortable with would be:

```
let joinLines = foldr (++) "" . intersperse "\n"
```

While playing with GHCI today, I wanted to see if I could compose `not` and `(==)` to replicate `(/=)`, but I wasn't really able to reason it out. `(==)` take two inputs, and `not` takes one. I thought that this might work:

```
let ne = not . (==)
```

With the assumption that the single `Bool` output of `(==)` would go to `not`, but it won't compile, citing the following error:

```
<interactive>:1:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `a0 -> Bool'
    Expected type: a0 -> Bool
      Actual type: a0 -> a0 -> Bool
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `(==)'
    In the expression: not . (==)
```

I wish I could say it meant much to me, but all I'm getting is that maybe the second argument that's passed to `(==)` is mucking things up for `not`? Can anybody help me understand a little better the logic behind this composition?

Comment: For the point-free lovers: the combinator you're looking for is `(.).(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> c`, or `fmap . fmap`.

Comment: @phipsgabler, would this work when the "first" function takes 3 arguments, like `(.).(.).(.)`?

Comment: @Alexey Phew. I'm sorry, I wrote this 8 years ago and haven't used Haskell for some years :) Try it in GHCI with `:t`, I guess?

Comment: @phipsgabler, i think it would, i hoped you could confirm it so that i do not have to think more about it :).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you start to remove one argument at the time, you get

```
ne x y = not (x == y)
       = (not . (x ==)) y
ne x   = not . (x ==)
       = not . ((==) x)
       = ((not .) . (==)) x
ne     = (not .) . (==)
```

basically, for every argument you need one `(.)`, properly associated.

The type of `(==)` is `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`. So if you write `whatever . (==)`, and pass a value `x` to that, you get `whatever ((==) x)`, but `(==) x` is a function `a -> Bool` (where `a` is the type of `x`, and an instance of `Eq`). So the `whatever` must accept arguments of function type.

Comment: Logically that makes sense to me, and it compiles, but results in a runtime error on (for example) `ne 1 1`: "No instance for (Num ())
      arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ())
    In the second argument of `ne', namely `1'
    In the expression: ne 1 1
    In an equation for `it': it = ne 1 1"

Comment: That's the monomorphism restriction. Give the binding a type signature, or disable the MR (`:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`). For ghci, the latter is easier, for files, I recommend the former.

Comment: Alright, totally new to me. Thanks. I'm sure this will help prepare me for stuff down the road. EDIT: Just tried the latter in ghci, and it does indeed work. I'll mark you as the answer when it lets me :p

Comment: To elaborate, `let ne = (not .) . (==)` is binding `ne` with a simple pattern binding [no function arguments] and without type signature. By the MR, entities bound by such bindings must have monomorphic types. Thus the type variable in the inferred type `ne :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` must be specialised to a concrete type. ghci's extended defaulting rules specialise it to `()`. In a file, that constraint is not defaultable [unless you enable `ExtendedDefaultRules`] and leads to a compilation error.

Answer (score 13):

Another useful operator is (.:), which is a combinator for an initial function taking two arguments:

```
f . g  $ x
f .: g $ x y
```

Comment: +1 For being informative. And apparently creating an account just to do so :p

Comment: Is this defined somewhere standard?  I usually call it `oo` (as in ML) and define it as: `oo = (.) . (.)`, but I'm not aware if it's in Base somewhere.

Comment: @singpolyma, nice abbreviation. Then `ooo = (.).(.).(.)` (for composing a function of 3 arguments with a function of one argument) and so forth...

Answer (score 3):

Explicit use of `curry` and `uncurry` can help switch between "multi-argument" and single-argument functions.

```
ne = curry (not . uncurry (==))
```

`uncurry` "fixes" `(==)` so that it takes a single argument `(x,y)` rather than separate `x` and `y` arguments. The resulting function can then be composed with `not` as expected. The composed function, then can be re-curried to accept separate arguments again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this makes any sense... but it looks readable to me

```
ne = (.) not . (==)
```

Comment: Yes. It's basically the same as `(not .) . (==)` in the accepted answer, though.